# How can I change a variable name based on a parameter passed to a function?

Tags: javascript

I have a function called `nameGenerator()` that takes a variable, `category`, as a parameter.

Before this function is defined, I have two "pairs" of wordlist arrays: `djentWords1` and `djentWords2`, and then `hardcoreWords1` and `hardcoreWords2`.

`nameGenerator()` defines the following variables:

1. `firstNum` and `secondNum`
2. `firstWord` and `secondWord`
3. `bandName`

The function generates two random numbers (`firstNum` and `secondNum`) between 0 and the length of either `djentWords1` & `djentWords2`, or `hardcoreWords1` & `hardcoreWords2`. My question is: can I pass `nameGenerator()` a parameter like "djent" or "hardcore", and based on that parameter, have it use the appropriate array length to generate the random number? Here's the function as-is:

```
//First category: djent
var djentWords1 = ["Aman", "Soul", "Cloud", "Calculate", "Pythagoran"];
var djentWords2 = ["NaaKi", "Circlet", "Cykul", "Consciousness", "Daaka"];

//Second category: hardcore
var hardcoreWords1 = ["SMASH", "RAGE", "LIFE", "THESE", "FIRST", "BRASS", "LAST"];
var hardcoreWords2 = ["FIST", "FIGHTER", "BREAKER", "SMASHER", "RUINER", "DAYS", "CHANCE"];


function nameGenerator (category){
    //Randomize
    var firstNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * categoryWords1.length); //categoryWords1 would either be djentWords1 or hardcoreWords1, based on the parameter passed to the function
    var secondNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * categoryWords2.length); //categoryWords2 would either be djentWords2 or hardcoreWords2, based on the parameter passed to the function
    var firstWord = categoryWords1[firstNum]; //firstWord = the word whose position corresponds to the first randomly-generated number
    var secondWord = categoryWords2[secondNum]; //secondWord = the word whose position corresponds to the second randomly-generated number
    var bandName = firstWord + secondWord;
}
```

Thanks in advance - and hopefully this wasn't too confusing. All help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not use an object (associative array)?

```
var words = {
    djent: [
        ["Aman","Soul","..."],
        ["NaaKi","Circlet","..."]
    ],
    hardcore: [
        ["..."],
        ["..."]
    ]
};
function nameGenerator(category) {
    var bandName = words[category][0][Math.floor(Math.random()*words[category][0].length)]
       + words[category][1][Math.floor(Math.random()*words[category][1].length)];
    return bandName;
}
```

Comment: Thank you SO much - worked like a charm!! I haven't used objects yet - so this was a great introduction :)

Answer (score 0):

you need to declare those variables as array attribute. try this :

```
var djent = {
    words1 : ["Aman", "Soul", "Cloud", "Calculate", "Pythagoran"],
    words2 : ["NaaKi", "Circlet", "Cykul", "Consciousness", "Daaka"]
}
var hardcore = {
    words1 : ["SMASH", "RAGE", "LIFE", "THESE", "FIRST", "BRASS", "LAST"],
    words2 : ["FIST", "FIGHTER", "BREAKER", "SMASHER", "RUINER", "DAYS", "CHANCE"]
}

function nameGenerator (category){
    var firstNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * window[category].words1.length)
       , secondNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * window[category].words2.length)
       , firstWord = window[category].words1[firstNum]
       , secondWord = window[category].words2[secondNum]
       , bandName = firstWord + secondWord;
    return bandName;
}
```